# Какие могут быть причины такого ступенчатого роста access-логов nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, логирование

Заметили очень странное изменение размера файла access-логов nginx. Ниже будет скриншот из Zabbix, по которому видно, что файл логов nginx растёт ступенчато (на графике показано свободное место в */var*, но там только логи nginx, к тому же проверяли изменение размера логов и в консоли). Видно, что замер "ступенек" на графике равномерно и пропорционально возрастает.

Самое странное, что в районе 22:00 файл логов стал весить **8Гб**, а потом сразу **4Гб**, при этом мы никаких действий не осуществляли и никаких "особых демонов ротации логов" на хосте нет.

Несколько уточнений:

- Трафик равномерный, никаких скачков в течение для не было.
- Ротация логов делается с помощью logrotate.d, который срабатывает один раз в сутки.
- Никаки бекап-скриптов, забирающий логи или как-то с ними взаимодействующий - нет.
- Конечно в /var/log есть еще файлы крона и tmp, но мы несколько раз в этот день проверяли размер всех файлов и это именно access.log растёт согласно графику.
- Логи в конфиге nginx настроены по дефолту:

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

Может есть какие-то особенности записи логов в nginx, о которых мы не догадались по доке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «проверяли изменение размера логов и в консоли» — и скачки, аналогичные скачку в 22:00, тоже поймали? На /var кроме nginx точно-преточно ничего? Может, всё-таки про какой-нибудь другой сервис, который есть из коробки, забыли?

Comment: Ещё касательно того аномального скачка подумалось, что может это какой-нибудь бэкап-скрипт, который бэкапит с копированием (но без точной конфигурации сервера это всё гадание)

Comment: И у вас в /var даже нет каталога tmp, который в некоторых случаях используется вместо /tmp ? лучше несколько раз в день сделайте `du -h /var` и посмотрите куда реально уходит место

Comment: попробуйте получить чуть более объективную картину, например, так: `while true; do echo -n $(date); wc -cl /путь/к/файлу; sleep 1800; done > /tmp/sizelog` — раз в 1800 секунд (цифра — просто для иллюстрации) в `/tmp/sizelog` будет добавляться строка с текущим временем и двумя цифрами — количеством строк и байт в указанном файле. чтобы избежать превратностей судьбы в виде разрыва связи, запускать команду, конечно, лучше в screen-/tmux-сессии.

Comment: @andreymal, по факту в /var/log есть еще файлы, tmp и крон, но мы конечно же проверяли несколько раз в этот день размер всех файлов - рос согласно графику только access.log. Никаких бекап сервисов нет, все очевидные варианты в виде ротации логов и постороннего вмешательства мы сразу проверили и отмели. В этом-то и аномалия. И особенно странно видеть такой _пропорциональный_ рост, а не спонтанный.

Comment: @Mike, подробнее об этом ответил выше.

Comment: Если почти все место на картинке - это действительно access_log то может у вас реально запросов скачкообразно становится больше, например вследствие какой нибудь атаки снаружи или запросов каких нибудь роботов. И вы точно рассмотрели весь /var, там же обычно еще почта в /var/spool, mysql в /var/lib/mysql может быть и еще куча всего. И вы реально видели, что именно лог у вас стал сначала больше а потом сразу меньше в 2 раза.

Comment: @Mike, да, это именно файл логов, несколько раз перепроверяли. Про трафик само собой были первые мысли, но график трафика на сетевом интерфейсе не показал никакой корреляции. Трафик был равномерный.

Comment: Если в логе дата-время в виде `[04/Apr/2016:23...` то можете статистику количества строк по часам посмотреть `perl -ne '$c{join("-",(m|\[(\d+)/(...)/(\d+):(\d+)|)[2,1,0,3])}++;END{print "$_ $c{$_}\n" for(sort keys %c);}' <access_log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем ответ оказался для нас слегка неожиданным, и суть заключалась в специфике работы XFS. Оказалось, что на диске по мере роста файла преаллоцируется пространство, что и объясняет скачкообразный рост показателей в команде du, не коррелирующий с динамикой трафика. Ниже ссылки для интересующихся, а также скрин графика из Zabbix, на котором мы решили отдельно мониторить файл логов (выводы du и stat). И как мы видим - du растёт ступенчато, а stat по динамике соответствует трафику:

- http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=055388a3188f56676c21e92962fc366ac8b5cb72
- https://serverfault.com/questions/406069/why-are-my-xfs-filesystems-suddenly-consuming-more-space-and-full-of-sparse-file

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]